# Upload file in PHP using DAV Protocol

Tags: php, file, webdav

Can someone please advise on uploading a file using the DAV protocol in PHP? I have had a look around the web and everything seems pretty over-complicated.

I will need to be uploading image files server side after user upload to a directory over DAV - is there a good PHP class available to do this?

Comment: [SabreDav](http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/) seems a very good current package, I've has some success using it in tests, but due to business decisions never employed in in production yet.

Comment: a more 'sysadmin' solution is having the distant DAV always mounted on the OS where you werbser is, as a distant fielsystem, then the webserver only access his 'local' filesystem and any auth negociation is done once at OS startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to [WebDAV Client Pear package](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_WebDAV_Client/), which implements a nice stream wrapper.

Comment: There is an example into the package. But you can do more or less things like this `    require '/path/to/pear/package.php';
    mkdir("webdav://www.example.com/foo/");
    file_put_contents("webdav://www.example.com/foo/bar.txt", $httpfile);
    $httpfile = file_get_contents("webdav://www.example.com/foo/bar.txt");
`

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can take a look at [SabreDAV](http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/), which is (unlike Pear's library) more regularly updated and implements new workarounds regarding Windows Vista & 7.